# Web API Converts custom Exception object to base Exception

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, exception

In developing a new web app utilizing Web API, I decided it would be a good practice to create a set of basic "response" classes that could house the results of a transaction, along with any warnings, errors, or any other necessary data in the future. Sample Below:

```cs
public class VoidResultsVM
{
    public bool IsSuccess { get; set; }
    public List<string> Results { get; set; }
    public List<Error> Errors { get; set; }
    public List<Alert> Alerts { get; set; }

    public VoidResultsVM()
    {
        Results = new List<string>();
        Errors = new List<Error>();
        Alerts = new List<Alert>();
    }
}
```

Tied into this response object is a list of custom Exception objects ("Error") that are derived from the Exception class in .NET. The main benefit to these classes are that we can identify exactly where an error occurred, and can add a custom message to the user to explain the error. Example below:

```cs
public class Error : Exception
{
    //public Exception Exception { get; set; }
    public string Origin { get; set; }
    public string UserMessage {get; set;}
    private DateTime timeStamp;
    public DateTime TimeStamp { get { return timeStamp; } set { timeStamp = DateTime.Now; } }
    public string Resolution { get; set; }


    public Error(string msg, Exception ex, string origin, string usermessage, DateTime @timestamp, string resolution = "")
        :base(msg, ex)
    {
        Origin = origin;
        UserMessage = usermessage;
        TimeStamp = @timestamp;
        Resolution = resolution;
    }
}
```

This object has already been extremely useful in developing and debugging the back end of the application and I am looking to keep that as much as possible.

The issue I am running into is that when trying a few API actions through, if one of these "Error" objects returns, Web API (I believe) is converting that "Error" object to its base class of Exception. See below for the JSON output from the API:

```js
{
    "IsSuccess": false,
    "Results": [],
    "Errors": [{
        "ClassName": "App.Models.Error",
        "Message": "Error getting history",
        "Data": {

        },
        "InnerException": {
            "ClassName": "System.Exception",
            "Message": "No records found for criteria",
            "Data": null,
            "InnerException": null,
            "HelpURL": null,
            "StackTraceString": "   at App.Database.DatabaseCore.GetHistory(HistorySearchVM history)",
            "RemoteStackTraceString": null,
            "RemoteStackIndex": 0,
            "ExceptionMethod": "8\nGetShipmentHistory\nApp.Database, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null\nApp.Database.DatabaseCore\nApp.Models.ViewModels.VoidResultsVM GetHistory(App.Models.ViewModels.HistorySearchVM)",
            "HResult": -2146233088,
            "Source": "App.Database",
            "WatsonBuckets": null
        },
        "HelpURL": null,
        "StackTraceString": null,
        "RemoteStackTraceString": null,
        "RemoteStackIndex": 0,
        "ExceptionMethod": null,
        "HResult": -2146233088,
        "Source": null,
        "WatsonBuckets": null
    }],
    "Alerts": []
}
```

So my question is this: How can I change my "Error" class so that Web API does not convert it back to the base class when posting back to the client? Is this something that can even be overridden?

**EDIT**

Below is the code from the API controller and Database to create and return this object. There is no logic in the code to convert the error object to or from an Exception object:

API Controller

```cs
    public VoidResultsVM Search(SearchVM vm)
    {
        DatabaseCore db = new DatabaseCore();
        VoidResultsVM results = new VoidResultsVM();
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                results = db.GetRecordById(vm.Id);
            }
            else
            {
                throw new HttpResponseException(Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest));
            };
        }
        catch (Error)
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest));
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest));
        }
        db = null;
        return results;
    }
```

Database

```cs
public Record GetRecordById(int id)
    {
        Record i = null;
        using (var transactionScope = TransactionScopeBuilder.CreateReadCommitted())
        {
            AppContext tempContext = null;
            try
            {
                using (tempContext = new AppContext())
                {
                    i = tempContext.Records.Where(x => x.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Common.Common.Log("", logName, Common.Common.LogLevels.ERROR, ex);
                throw new Error(ex.Message, ex, "DATABASE", "", DateTime.Now);
            }
            finally
            {
                transactionScope.Complete();
            }
        }
        return i;
    }
```

Comment: When you debug is it a `Error` type in your code all the way through? Can you provide the code where you actually return/serialize the response?

Comment: As far I know that information is only returned because you enabled exception details. Maybe it doesn't converts standard properties of the exception. Take a look at [this](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/error-handling/exception-handling#exceptionfilters) and find the section regarding Exception Filters. The exception that you have is fine, but I would convert that to an error message model. It is typical bad practice to expose the stacktrace of an exception in an API. That should just be logged in a debug log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After working through a few solutions, I decided to go with Michael's suggestion in returning a dedicated view model that holds the extra information that has the most debugging use, and logging the full Error model only.